# Static files are not served

Tags: node.js, express, static

I want to serve css file(s) from the 'css' folder...

I have this line of code so far :

```
app.use("/static", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + "/../views/public/css")));
```

I put `/../` to go a path backwards.

and this is my folder hierarchy:

[image: Folder hierarchy]

I go to `/static/styles.css` - the server can not get this

Comment: Usually the path starts at the your root file (ex: server.js)

What does your dir structure look like?   if you have server.js in the root folder then it would be /views/public/css

Comment: There is a link to the image of my folder hierarchy in my post!!!
the __dirname is starting from the current folder ;)

Comment: Looks like what I described is what you need to do assuming app.js is your main file

Comment: Thanks... I forgot I'm developing with typescript... and I actually run the `app.js` file not the `.ts` one

Comment: @TaylorAckley There's absolutely no need to change your directory structure.  He can do whatever he wants.

Comment: No, he doesn't need to change the directory structure and that's not what I said.  The issue is he doesn't need to go back a level... it's relative to the root file.

Comment: He's highlighted app.ts right there in his image...

Comment: @MarkSpencer Show us what errors you're seeing, server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in my comment, node looks for static directories based off the main JS file.  Try it without the `/../` and it should work.

Comment: His app is in `src`.  He's using `__dirname`, which is the path that the **currently executing script resides in**.  https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html  Node doesn't "look for static directories" at all.  It does what you tell it.

Comment: that is the `app.ts` but it compiles to the `app.js` which is not in the `src` fodler

Comment: Good stuff , @brad